# Apache HttpCilent: Timeout issue within a corporate network

Tags: java, timeout, apache-httpclient-4.x

This question worths 50$ bill :)

I have a simple Java application that retrieves some data from a remote server by Get http request. When I run it from my home it works, and when I run it inside my university it does not, it gives me : "Connection timed out: connect" error.

- We do NOT have a proxy in my university, I verified this with the adminstrator,
- I can access the URL of the remote server from the navigator and test the post/get and it works;
- If it is a firewall problem, then why the navigator can access the server and retrieve the data?

Here is my code:

```
package API;
import Controllers.Computed_IndicatorController;
import Controllers.DB_Connection_Factory;
import Controllers.DatasetController;
import Controllers.MessageController;
import Controllers.UserController;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Vector;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import Entities.Computed_Indicator;
import Entities.Dataset;
import Entities.Message;
import Entities.User;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class GetTweets1 {

private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    public GetTweets1(){}





    public static void RetrieveAndStoreMessages() throws IOException, JSONException, SQLException{ 



            String url =  "...my URL...";
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);  
            //request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            request.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials("account", "password"), "UTF-8", false));//("account", "password"), "UTF-8", false));
            //request.addHeader("Accept" ,"application/json; charset=utf-8");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);  


    }    



    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception{

        RetrieveAndStoreMessages();
   }            
}
```

Can you please help me to resolve this problem? I am willing to to give a 50$ bill for the one who resolves it for me.

Comment: You have a few options, such as checking the request sent programmatically actually matches the one sent with your browser in terms of headers, authentication, etc. You could also troubleshoot your server by try a remote debug socket or checking the logs depending on access, etc. Note that SO is not a paid for service, so it doesn't make sense for you to offer currency for assistance (unless that was a joke).

Comment: Thank you very very much Mena, I resolved the issue thanks to your idea of taking a look at the header

Comment: good stuff, glad to help :)